# NSFetchRequest for an attribute's max value.The result is different every time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfetchrequest

NSFetchRequest for an attribute's max value.

But the result turns to a different one every time.

This is my code.

```
- (NSInteger)getMaxTimeStamp
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
```

`NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Relation" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[fetchRequest setIncludesPropertyValues:NO]; //only fetch the managedObjectID

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"ts" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

NSError * error = nil;
Relation *relation = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error].lastObject;

//error handling goes here
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}

if (relation.ts) {
    return (NSInteger)relation.ts;
}else {
    return 0;
}`

}

and I looped 10 times for result logs

- 2012-07-03 11:05:55.831 Edusorf[1956:15803] max time stamp: 136934464
- 2012-07-03 11:05:55.831 Edusorf[1956:15803] max time stamp: 137170400
- 2012-07-03 11:05:55.832 Edusorf[1956:15803] max time stamp: 137106624
- 2012-07-03 11:05:55.832 Edusorf[1956:15803] max time stamp: 137154096
- 2012-07-03 11:05:55.833 Edusorf[1956:15803] max time stamp: 137107392
- 2012-07-03 11:05:55.833 Edusorf[1956:15803] max time stamp: 137115728
- 2012-07-03 11:05:55.833 Edusorf[1956:15803] max time stamp: 137110608
- 2012-07-03 11:05:55.834 Edusorf[1956:15803] max time stamp: 136828592
- 2012-07-03 11:05:55.834 Edusorf[1956:15803] max time stamp: 136995824
- 2012-07-03 11:05:55.835 Edusorf[1956:15803] max time stamp: 136925072

Could anybody helps me out? thx~~

Comment: what is the type of `ts` in the data model and how is it being set?

Comment: @KDaker ts is a integer in the data model.

Comment: @KDaker I didn't touch the setting stuffs.They are all created by xcode automatically.

Comment: it could be that the value for ts is too big for an integer type. Try changing it to `double` or `Integer 64` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: also, why not use `date` for a time stamp?

Comment: @KDaker the **double** way doesn't work. and I also tried for **int64** type.It doesn't work too...  the **date** type returns right result~~ haha~~ thanks for your help~~ haha

Comment: no problem. do you mind selecting my answer if my comments helped you out :) thanks.

Comment: Not related to the question, but you shouldn't call -setIncludesProperties:NO since you immediately fault in the property by reading the value in ts.

Comment: @JasonCoco yah~ you are right~~ do you mind telling me more about when to use *** -setIncludesProperties:NO ***?? :) thanks~~

Comment: It's useful if you're just fetching managed object ids or you just want a count of something or you don't want to evict the current cache row because you know you're not going to fault in the object for a while (like in prefetching). In almost all normal cases, however, you wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the `ts` type to Date in the data model.